# Change necessary mouse speed to get mouse cursor to monitor with smaller resolution

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse, resolution

I use two monitors (22" and 27") with windows 7. They differ in screen resolution that's why there's always a part of the bigger monitor "overlapping" the smaller one.

To pass this overlapping part while moving my mouse from the 27" to the 22" I have to move the mouse very fast... and that's way too fast for me. I already searched for tools and registry entries - but without success. Does anyone know how to lower this necessary mouse speed?

Or in other words: I want to move my mouse seamlessly from one monitor to the other without getting stuck anywhere or changing mouse speed (while using different screen resolutions). Any ideas?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Psycogeek! After reading your text I realised that I used the wrong word... it's not the overlapping part that makes trouble it's the part the monitors are NOT overlapping (sry, english is not my native language). So it's this virtual wall I have troubles with... to break this wall I need a high mouse speed. And this speed I want to lower. An eventually jumping cursor due to different resolutions is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a Low-res monitor as a second monitor before, the problem I had.

Where the resolution differs, there is a virtual wall
[image]
This Virtual wall will not allow the mouse to pass, because , there is "no where for it to go" On the monitor which does not have screen there.

**THe mouse never crosses that wall, but going really fast the mouse might move more vertically till it pases through the open space.**

The location of this virtual wall can be adjusted , by moving the other monitor around in this display setting.

[image]
The change in the picture is exaggerated here to show what it is like when the resolutions are way off (which they aren't anymore).  This picture shows that where the monitor lines up at is adjustable.  You will still have a virtual wall for the mouse to crash into as long as the resolutions are not the same. It is possible in the settings to move where the monitors line up.

If you are racing the mouse across the screen to pass through this virtual wall, it could seem like that is how you got there.  I was doing the same thing to try and jump screens with a trackball and getting quite confused too.

Could you test by adjusting the position of the 2nd monitor in the display settings of windows and pass the mouse at the top bottom or middle of the screen WithOut racing the mouse. See if that has anything to do with it?
Realign where these displays butt up against each other in the settings again, and test again. Like align to the top or bottom.

If your in the clear zone where the monitors both meet with the mouse, and speeding the mouse across the screen is the ONLY way to get it to hop over there.  Then we need to know what software is being applied to the mouse?
What is the mouse type?  What is the mouse Brand?  What software is being used beyond the windows generic mouse driver?    Other than that there may be settings Hot tracking or x-mouse or something that could be effecting it, although I would not know how.